# what is a non-SDK interface

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

After searching new Android P features, I came across the non-SDK interfaces restriction. and my question is,

What is a non-SDK interface or an SDK interface?
What is the difference between them? specially that makes non-SDK once better.
Examples of popular SDK and non-SDK interfaces available for android.

P.S. I came across abstract answers differentiating between SDK and API interfaces but it didn't fulfill my questions :/

Comment: Well, there is an explanations in official docs ... what didn't you understand?

Comment: @Selvin As you can notice from my questions, I have a problem identifying a non-sdk interface, I need the what or the identity of it, not the why which the documentation focuses on

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces):

> Generally speaking, SDK interfaces are those ones found documented in the Android framework [Package Index](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Not everything in the framework appears in the documentation. Classes, methods, fields, and such marked with `@hide` in the source code are available at runtime [but are not part of the SDK](https://commonsware.com/blog/2018/01/18/think-hard-about-hide.html) and do not appear in the documentation. These items can only be accessed by unconventional means, such as reflection.

That is what Android P is [starting to ban](https://commonsware.com/blog/2018/03/01/hide-penny-drops.html).

For years, I have been advising developers not to access such things, because they are unreliable. Any Android device may not have the hidden stuff, due to changes based on the Android version or device manufacturer/ROM modder tweaks. Now, Google is going to enforce this advice more firmly, at least in some cases.

> specially that makes non-SDK once better

They are not "better". However, they may offer access to certain features that are not available in the SDK, for one reason or another (e.g., API is not settled yet).

Comment: Google play reports "Issue: Usage of non-SDK interfaces"  in *test results for APK* of my app. However I am not using any hidden API in my own source code. The question is how to identify the troublemaking library?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: On Android 9.0, you should see some messages in LogCat about the non-SDK interface usage. Also on 9.0, you can set up `penaltyListener()` in `StrictMode` and `detectNonSdkApiUsage()` in the `VmPolicy.Builder` to find out about non-SDK API usage in near-real-time.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber if you use androidx support library it uses hidden method `computeFitSystemWindows` for `setContentView()` resulting in this violation report on Android P

Comment: @materemias So do we just ignore that violation report?

Comment: I am using AndroidX on 500k+ devices. Do I just drop it? And if yes, what are the alternatives?

Comment: @PrimožKralj: Neither this question nor this answer pertain to AndroidX.

Comment: Hmm, I am getting non-SDK violation reports stemming from AndroidX. But I admit I just started researching the issue.. that, and it's saturday 4am.

Comment: @PrimožKralj: If you are on the latest versions of those libraries, hopefully the only reports will be for graylist entries, not blacklist ones. It is up to Google (the AndroidX developers) to talk to Google (the people who create the non-SDK interface lists) to get AndroidX working on newer versions of Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare **Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)** I getting this warning in my logcat so how can I solve this? I'm not using **AudioManager** in my project.

Comment: @AbhiS: Presumably, some library that your project uses (directly or transitively) is using that method.

Comment: Is there any way to tell if something is a non-sdk interface?  Is there a straight-forward way to check code to see all the non-sdk interfaces?

Comment: @SMBiggs: "Is there any way to tell if something is a non-sdk interface?" -- if you have to use reflection to access it, odds are that it is a non-SDK interface.